# is there equivalent form of that limit in terms of derivative?

Tags: limits, derivatives

Given the limit:
$$\lim _{\Delta t\to 0}\frac{\Delta x\Delta y}{\Delta t}$$ where both x and y are function of t. Is this equivalent to derivative of product or something similar?

Comment: what exactly are $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$?

Comment: Does it matter? If $$\lim _{\Delta t\to 0}\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}$$ was asked, would you ask for what is \Delta x

Comment: it is important to understand your formula, isn't it?

Comment: We just know x and y are t dependent. Not explicitly given.

Comment: I meant, is $\Delta x = x(\Delta t) - x(0)$ or something like that?

Comment: you can think like $$x_k - x_(k-1)$$

Comment: Is there a special reason why the expression is like this ?

Comment: sorry for the format error in last comment.

Comment: @Salihcyilmaz To answer your question. It is not equivalent to the derivative of a product of two functions. I see just now, that Zach has already answered the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question, it indeed is not equivalent to taking the product of two derivatives. But, as you are about to see, your intuition was fairly close.

$$\lim_{\Delta t \to 0} {{\Delta x \Delta y} \over {\Delta t}}=\lim_{\Delta t \to 0} {{\Delta x} \over {\sqrt{\Delta t}}} \cdot \lim_{\Delta t \to 0} {{ \Delta y} \over {\sqrt{\Delta t}}}={{dx} \over {dt^{1/2}}} \cdot {{dy} \over {dt^{1/2}}}$$

So the result is the product of two [Alpha Derivatives](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/661359/alpha-derivative-concept). In short, the alpha derivative "smooths over" areas of a function with a near infinite rate of change. So, for well behaved functions,

$$\lim_{\Delta t \to 0} {{\Delta x \Delta y} \over {\Delta t}}=0$$

Comment: Thats interesting, total new concept for me.