# Example of a discontinuous function for which limit of the differential quotient exists in $\mathbb R\cup\{-\infty,+\infty\}$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, examples-counterexamples, solution-verification

I am just asking this question for my verification of own answer.
I have taken as example the function $f(x)=1/x$ if $x\neq 0$ and $0$ if $x=0$.
Here $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=+\infty$.Is this example correct?
Note: I am also asking this question for sharing what I know or learn with other members in the community.

Comment: @Thomas I am just sharing my learning with the stackexchange community,I could also post it as answer to own question.

Comment: Somewhat related is [$\alpha$-derivative (concept)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/661359/13130), and more related is a google search for ["infinite derivative" + "Cantor function"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22infinite+derivative%22+%22Cantor+function%22).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct. Note that an example of a continuous such function is $x\mapsto\sqrt[3]{x}$ at $x=0$.